# Cannot re-size/close maximized window

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a Chrome window that went full screen and just the window content is visible, not the widgets around it (title bar, buttons, ...).

It is working properly, but I cannot re-size or close it.

I looked in Chrome's processes/threads list, but I could not find it.

Is there a way to close such a window?

Answer (score 1):

If you need other actions than closing, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and from menu which opens, select appropriate action: Move, Resize, Maximize, Minimize, Close.

The above keyboard shortcut works with all desktop windows.